# Oracle procedure not getting invoked from EF6?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I've create a procedure in my Oracle database for switching the status of a specific trigger like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYSCHEMA.PROC_SWITCH_TRIGGER_STATUS AS
    vStatus VARCHAR(10);
    vAction VARCHAR(10):= 'ENABLE';
BEGIN
    SELECT STATUS INTO vStatus FROM USER_TRIGGERS
        WHERE TRIGGER_NAME = 'MY_TRIGGER_NAME';
    IF vStatus = 'ENABLED' THEN
        vAction := 'DISABLE';
    END IF;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER MY_TRIGGER_NAME ' || vAction;
END PROC_SWITCH_TRIGGER_STATUS;
/
```

I've verified this perfectly works when executed directly in the database, the thing is I want to execute it from c# code using EF. I thought with one of the following statements it would be possible:

- `db.Database.SqlQuery<object>("BEGIN MYSCHEMA.PROC_SWITCH_TRIGGER_STATUS END;");`
- `db.Database.SqlQuery<object>("CALL MYSCHEMA.PROC_SWITCH_TRIGGER_STATUS();");`
- `db.Database.SqlQuery<object>("EXEC MYSCHEMA.PROC_SWITCH_TRIGGER_STATUS;");`

After executing them there's no effect in the trigger' status, it remains the same. Note I used `object` in the `SqlQuery` generic type parameter 'cause my procedure returns nothing, I don't really know if that's the way but it gives no error back. I test it isn't working with the following:

```
class _Status { public string STATUS {get; set;} }
...
string q = "SELECT STATUS FROM USER_TIGGERS WHERE TRIGGER_NAME='MY_TRIGGER_NAME'";
_Status sBefore = db.Database.SqlQuery<_Status>(q);
<execution of any of the above procedure calls>
_Status sAfter = db.Database.SqlQuery<_Status>(q);
Console.WriteLine(sBefore.FirstOrDefault()?.STATUS);
Console.WriteLine(sAfter.FirstOrDefault()?.STATUS);
```

The output of the above is:

```
ENABLED
ENABLED
```

I'm using ODP.NET, Managed Driver and EF 6.2 and my question/doubt would be: What can you advise me to do in order the call/invocation of the procedure affect the trigger' status. I'm using same USER/SCHEMA when connecting to the database and in the connection string. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the trouble, I rushed myself a little bit in asking. Any way, there's a `ExecuteSqlCommand` in the `Database` property that allowed me achieve what I want. There's two ways of invoking:

- `db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CALL MYSCHEMA.PROC_SWITCH_TRIGGER_STATUS()")`
- `db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("BEGIN MYSCHEMA.PROC_SWITCH_TRIGGER_STATUS; END;")`